# find data array in computed vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

i have data

```
<div class="marginleft">{{locations}}</div>
```

and this my computed

```
 computed : {
 ...mapState({ result_estimate: (state) => state.res_estimate }),

 ...mapState({ prov: (state) => state.provinsi }),

 locations(){
   return this.prov.find((o) => o.id_provinsi === this.result_estimate.id_location).provinsi
 },
}
```

state.res_estimate have json like this

```
  {
      id: 3,
      id_location : 2
  }
```

state.prov have json like this

```
  {
      id_location : 1
      provinsi : canada
  },
  {
      id_location : 2
      provinsi : australia
  }
```

i made a function to search province name based on province_id
but my logs get an error

> this.prov.find(...) is undefined

but `return this.prov.find((o) => o.id_provinsi === 7 (manual param)).provinsi` success

why ?

Comment: I assume `state.prov` has something that is not an array at some point. Just because it does contain valid content when you check it, does not mean it contains valid content when the error occurs. I would expect an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')` or `Uncaught TypeError: this.prov.find is not a function` though.

Comment: solve it, I was just wrong ===
correct == 

thanks